# How to write query with like (NOT IN) in Mybatis for Postgresql db?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

I have to delete the records from one of the table in mybatis for the PostgreSQL database.

So IN and NOT IN clause is not supported/working for PostgreSQL database with LIST or array as in input for me.

For a select query with array as input **IN** clause is not working but **ANY** clause is working for me so I am trying something like NOT ANY in mybatis for Postgresql database.

```
@Delete("delete from test where resource_key NOT ANY(#{resourceIds}::int[]) and type=#{type}")
public Integer deleteFromTest(@Param("type") Integer type,@Param("resourceIds") int[] resourceIds);

@Delete("delete from test where resource_key NOT IN(#{resourceIds}) and type=#{type}")
public Integer deleteFromTest(@Param("type") Integer type,@Param("resourceIds") int[] resourceIds);
```

How to write a mybatis delete mapper method with NOT IN or something like NOT IN to use LIST or array as an input to that method?

Comment: The equivalent of `NOT IN (..)` is  `<> ALL (...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks.... <> ALL working for me